# Cannot override apply function

Tags: kotlin

I came across the following code:

```
import io.reactivex.Observable
import io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

    class ExpBackoff(
      private val jitter: Jitter,
      private val delay: Long,
      private val unit: TimeUnit,
      private val retries: Int = 0
    ) : Function<Observable<out Throwable>, Observable<Long>> {

      @Throws(Exception::class)
      override fun apply(observable: Observable<out Throwable>): Observable<Long> {
        return observable
            .zipWith(Observable.range(1, retries), BiFunction<Throwable, Int, Int> { _, retryCount ->
              retryCount
            })
            .flatMap { attemptNumber -> Observable.timer(getNewInterval(attemptNumber), unit) }
      }

      private fun getNewInterval(retryCount: Int): Long {
        var newInterval = (delay * Math.pow(retryCount.toDouble(), 2.0) * jitter.get()).toLong()
        if (newInterval < 0) {
          newInterval = Long.MAX_VALUE
        }
        return newInterval
      }
    }
```

located at:

https://leandrofavarin.com/exponential-backoff-rxjava-operator-with-jitter

This code doesn't compile. This line is wrong:

```
Function<Observable<out Throwable>, Observable<Long>>
```

Function only takes a single argument. I am really confused here. The person who wrote the article clearly indicates that he wrote this code and I assume it works or at least worked at the time he wrote it. But I doubt that Kotlin changed the interface for Function. Even if I remove the second parameter, the code will not compile because the apply function cannot be overridden as this is not part of the Function interface.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Make sure you have import the correct `Function` class.

Comment: Think you're looking at the wrong [`Function`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/functions/Function.html).

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I added the imports to the code above. How do I know which Function to use? Unfortunately, there is no github project for that code, so I have to assume that Function is the one provided by Kotlin (which unfortunately does state that it is an experimental feature - so maybe it was changed)

Comment: My previous comment contains a link to the `Function` I think you need. If not, your guess is as good as mine... Maybe ping the article author?

Comment: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/functions/Function.html

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen The link you provided was the correct one. I am surprised that Android Studio did not offer me multiple alternatives as it normally does. I had to prepend the package name to Function (io.reactivex.functions.Function). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing correct `Function` import. The following code works in my IDE.

```
import io.reactivex.Observable
import io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction
import io.reactivex.functions.Function
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

class ExpBackoff(
    private val jitter: Jitter,
    private val delay: Long,
    private val unit: TimeUnit,
    private val retries: Int = 0
) : Function<Observable<out Throwable>, Observable<Long>> {

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun apply(observable: Observable<out Throwable>): Observable<Long> {
        return observable
            .zipWith(Observable.range(1, retries), BiFunction<Throwable, Int, Int> { _, retryCount ->
                retryCount
            })
            .flatMap { attemptNumber -> Observable.timer(getNewInterval(attemptNumber), unit) }
    }

    private fun getNewInterval(retryCount: Int): Long {
        var newInterval = (delay * Math.pow(retryCount.toDouble(), 2.0) * jitter.get()).toLong()
        if (newInterval < 0) {
            newInterval = Long.MAX_VALUE
        }
        return newInterval
    }
}
```